# How to use model.findbyid and query inside it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is a simple question for you guys...I am wondering how can I acess a specific Id that is inside the "followers", after querying the User by its id. In other words i am searching for the user by its Id, and then I want to check the ids that are inside the followers. 
For example: I have an Id saved in one variable "x", and I want to check if this Id "x" is inside of the followers array.

The model looks like this:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      followers: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        ]
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

And the code that I am using is this one:

```
User.findById(req.params.id,'followers', function(err,name){
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
      } else{
        console.log(name);
      }
    });
```

It looks like I can print the user id and the id's that are inside the "followers", but i am not managing to see if the desired Id is inside of "followers" array or not.Can anyone help me with it?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create nested for loop because you have an array of users according to user schema and each user has an array of followers and to solve this, you need to create for loop for user schema and inside that loop you will loop through all followers inside that user and check whether the id that you have equals to their id.

Comment: Thank you, I am actually trying to do it... in case that I am comparing two objects, the right thing to do is to use .equals to compare them, right?

Comment: Ok, I tried to use a for loop and I was able to check if the data was there... This is a great relief for me!

Answer (score 0):

Since `followers` is an array of IDs (document references), if the query is for a single follower match you can use a shorthand of `{followers: SOME_ID}` or if it is an array then you can use `{followers: {$all: [SOME_ID, SOME_OTHER_ID]}}`. See the Mongo [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#match-an-array) for more information.

Using an array to match for example would look like the following.

```js
User.findOne({_id: req.params.id, followers: {$all: [SOME_ID, SOME_OTHER_ID]}}, function(err, name) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(name);
  }
});
```

Comment: So, I have tried this code and it is giving me a "unexpected toke {" pointing to the first token after User.findOne... Is this the correct way to query in this case?

Comment: @RogerPeixoto Sorry, there was a typo. It *should* work now.